# Theme.of(context).iconTheme is different from IconTheme.of(context)

Tags: flutter

I'm working on a Flutter application and encounter a weird bug.

Somehow, `Theme.of(context).iconTheme` becomes different from my `IconTheme.of(context)`. Why are they different? And how do I change my ThemeData so that `IconTheme.of(context)` will change as well?

Comment: Can you please include code of how you are assigning your `Theme.of(context).iconTheme` and how you are using your `IconTheme.of(context)` and what is the difference you see?

Answer (score 1):

I found out that I set the IconTheme in AppBar to be different from the app's theme, which is the parent of the widget where `Theme.of(context).iconTheme` becomes different from my `IconTheme.of(context).`.